# javafx TitledPane click event only for Title

Tags: javafx

Is there any way I can have an event that only triggers if I click the Title of a TitledPane?

I have several Nodes in a Graph Editor and currently they are draggable.
But I want them only to drag when i drag the Title not if I click anywhere on the pane.

the mouseClick event seems not to work for me.
Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't set the text on the titled pane, but instead create a label and set it as the graphic for the titled pane. Then you can register a mouse handler with the label:

```
private TitledPane createClickableTitledPane(String text) {
    Label label = new Label(text);
    label.setOnMouseClicked(e -> System.out.println("Click on "+text));
    TitledPane titledPane = new TitledPane();
    titledPane.setGraphic(label);
    return titledPane ;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it basically does what I want, but my problem now is that the event is only for the label text, is there a way to get the event for the whole title?

Answer (score 1):

```
StackPane titleRegion = (StackPane) titledPane.lookup(".title");
titleRegion.setOnMouseClicked(System.out::println);
```

---

#### EDIT:

Sometimes `titledPane.lookup(".title")` returns `null` which means [CSS is not applied to the node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34861832/597657). To resolve this issue, you need to use `applyCss()` and `layout()` on the pane that contains the `TitledPane`.

#### See:

- [JavaFX TitledPane lookup(.title) returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49500803/597657)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I tried using the applyCss and layout approach but wasn't working. I ended up just throwing the lookups on Platform.runLater which worked fine.